# Convert Swift 3 Function to Swift 4

Tags: swift

im struggling in converting this function to Swift 4

```
func buildIndex(records: [Record]) -> [[Record]] {
    var g = [NSDate: [Record]]()
    for e in records {
        if (g[e.time] == nil) {
            g[e.time] = []
        }
        g[e.time]!.append(e) // grouping by `time`
    }
    return sorted(g.keys) { (a: NSDate, b: NSDate) in
        a.compare(b) == .OrderedAscending // sorting the outer array by time
    }
    // sorting the inner arrays by `name`
    .map { sorted(g[$0]!) { $0.name < $1.name } } 
}
```

I hope someone can help me.

Comment: What happens when you try? Which parts are you struggling with?

Comment: Problem is solved thanks you for your time

Comment: Don't use variable names like `e`, `g`. Future you will hate you for it, and any other people who need to read/maintain this code in the future.

Comment: Swift's sort isn't guaranteed to be stable, so doing 2 sorts in a row like that isn't guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it

```
func buildIndex(records: [Record]) -> [[Record]] {
    var g = [NSDate: [Record]]()
    for e in records {
        if (g[e.time] == nil) {
            g[e.time] = []
        }
        g[e.time]!.append(e) // grouping by `time`
    }

    return g.keys.sorted { (a: NSDate, b: NSDate) in
        a.compare(b as Date) == .orderedAscending // sorting the outer array by time
        }
        // sorting the inner arrays by `name`
        .map { g[$0]!.sorted { $0.name < $1.name } }
}
```

Hope it helped you.

Comment: Certainly not `NSDate`. Not even in Swift 3. There is a native Swift type `Date`

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot to clean up here. The variable names are obviously a disaster, but so is the forced unwrapping. All that can be replaced with a simple call to [`Dictionary.init(grouping:by:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2995342-init)

```
import Foundation

struct Record {
    let time: Date
    let name: String
}

func buildIndex(records: [Record]) -> Any {
    return Dictionary(grouping: records, by: { $0.time })
        .mapValues { $0.sorted { $0.name < $1.name} }
        .sorted { (pair1, pair2) in pair1.key < pair2.key }
}
```